# Will barcode scanning get better performance if you reduce the metadataObjectTypes it can register?

Tags: ios, barcode

When doing barcode scanning with iPhone camera and the built in `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` 
You set a

```
let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
output.metadataObjectTypes = output.availableMetadataObjectTypes
```

Will the scanner get better performance when scanning barcodes if i do not set all available types and just go for `EAN 13` which is the one i need? You would think it might not need to as much checking and then give better results.

Comment: I would not recommend using AVFoundation to scan EAN codes. Use ZBar instead.

Comment: It takes AVFoundation much longer to recognise EAN codes. Even when I used a separate thread for `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`. It had also problems when I moved the EAN code further away from the camera. It could not find codes from distances where ZBar was really quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly **YES** since you reduce the complexity of things to look for.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureMetadataOutput/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureMetadataOutput/metadataObjectTypes) state

> This property is used to filter the metadata objects reported by the receiver. Only metadata objects whose type matches one of the strings in this property are forwarded to the delegate’s captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection: method for processing.

and

> The default is an empty NSArray object, and as a result, no metadata objects are forwarded to the delegate’s captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection: method. The same result can be achieved by setting the property to nil. This default behavior maximizes both performance and battery life.

Especially the last paragraph is of importance here since it implies that what you set `metadataObjectTypes` to impacts the performance.

It might still be that setting `metadataObjectTypes` does not cause performance improvement, but it has the potential to do so and will definitely not cause negative performance impacts. Therefore you should set the `metadataObjectTypes` to all the types (or just the one type) you want to actually capture.